# uploading file size

Tags: php, mysql

As we all know, By default in PHP+MySQL, we can upload a file of size 1.4MB (max).

1) My Question is how can i increase the limitation of this uploading file size?

2) What is the maximum limitation for file to be uploaded in database?

Thanx for viewing my query and special thanx for answering my questin.

Answer (score 3):

In php.ini  the following parameters have an effect

- file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- max_input_time
- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size

Parameters are explained [here](http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php)

EDIT:
For mysql limits see the reference manual, there is a parameter [max_allowed_paket](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) which defaults to 1GB, there maybe also timeouts when inserting huge amounts of data.

Comment: I went through your sight. It is preety good. But some sort of information is missed(what i want to know)

Comment: Although it's in the linked page, I'd thought I'd mention apache's LimitRequestBody specifically here in the comments too. Has burned me in the past while hunting through PHP-settings :).

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directives in `php.ini`
2. Google for *mysql data types*, you'll find limitations of each data type. But IIRC blob types are unlimited (ie. limited by disk size).

Comment: Thanx! can you post me your php.ini file with increased value to  me on my email id: anupprakash36@gmail.com

Actually i want to check the differences between your and mine.
and other thing i heard or you can see read from some website is that, There is a file name my.ini where i would have to make some changes. Can you help me about this my.ini file

Comment: First of all `my.ini` is probably **MySQL** configuration file, not PHP. Secondly comparison of out INIs is pointless. Just edit directives you need to change, save the file and restart the server -  that's all. If something would be still incorrect then post another question on SO.